# node js clustering is repeating the same task on all 8 processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to enable clustering in my node js app. Currently I use this snippet to enable it:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // Count the machine's CPUs
  var cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;

  // Create a worker for each CPU
  for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  // Listen for dying workers
  cluster.on('exit', function () {
    cluster.fork();
  });
}
```

And basically my code performs writes to a Firebase database based on conditions. The problem is that the writes are occurring 8 times each, rather than one worker just taking care of one write task, it seems that all threads are performing all tasks. Is there a way to avoid this? If so, can someone point me in the direction of some resources on this? I can't find anything on google for using Firebase with node js clustering. Here is an example of the way one of my functions work (ref is my firebase reference):

```
ref.child('user-sent').on('child_added', function(snapshot) {

            var message = snapshot.child('message');

            payload['user-received/'] = message;

            ref.update(payload); // this occurs once for each fork so it updates 8 times
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're spawning 8 threads and each thread attaches a listener on the same location (`user-sent`), then each thread will fire the `child_added` event for each child under that location. This is the expected behavior.

If you want to implement a worker queue, where each node under `user-sent` is only handled by one thread, you'll have to use a work-distribution mechanism that ensures only one thread can claim each node.

The [firebase-queue library](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue) implements such a work claim mechanism, using Firebase Database transactions. It's been used to scale to a small to medium number of workers (think < 10, not dozens).

Comment: Thanks Frank! I'm wondering why you'd advise against scaling over 10 workers? Is it something to do with transactions not scaling well? I might need to scale 10+, but for me the main bottleneck is a CPU intensive calculation and not actually updating my Firebase so i might be able to somehow offload that part somewhere else.

Comment: At some point you'll hit contention issues, as all workers are modifying the same task queue. It all depends on the size of the operations of course, so ymmv. If you hit such limits, consider alternative work distribution systems. Something less democratic (e.g. a single work distribution service) is likely to scale further, since there's likely to be less contention.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. One last thing if you don't mind, I've written a simple queue implementation for pushing the payloads to Firebase and started 6 processes with 100 items in queue just to test how well the workers distribute work and I'm getting 3 workers doing almost all the work with the other three only taking 2 tasks each out of the full 100, as shown here http://i.imgur.com/V1WwCI9.png do you know maybe why this is occurring? Would it depend on my code or is this a function of how queue is implemented? Thanks again.

Comment: Good question that I unfortunately don't know the answer to. If you suspect that it's related to the queue implementation, it might be worth posting an issue with minimal reproduction on the repo.